# sudo rm -rf directory/* does not work with certain permission settings

Tags: linux, permissions, rm

I have a directory `/var/opt/gitlab/backups` with the following permissions:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo ls -la /var/opt/gitlab/backups
total 1316296
drwx------.  2 git  root         63 1月  21 21:44 .
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root root       4096 1月  21 21:39 ..
-rw-------.  1 git  git  1347880960 1月  21 21:44 1642819457_2022_01_21_14.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
```

Now the following command does not remove anything

```
sudo rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/backups/*
```

While the following command removes the directory and everything inside

```
sudo rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/backups/
```

Also the following command will remove the specific file

```
sudo rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/backups/1642819457_2022_01_21_14.1.2-ee_gitlab_backup.tar
```

It's only the file wildcard way does not work (which unfortunately is what I want)

However what I want is only removing the files inside and not removing the directory. I suspect it's because of the permission settings but changing the permissions is not an option for me. The directory owner and permissions are set automatically by a third-party software and I would like not to mess around.

Is there any way to achieve the "removing all files inside the directory but not the directory itself" effect?

Comment: What's the error message you are getting?

Comment: There is no error message. Just does not remove anything.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `r` from the `-rf`?

Comment: It's the same effect. No error and nothing removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcards are expanded by your shell.  In order for

```
rm /var/opt/gitlab/backups/*
```

to work, then you must have permission to list the contents of `/var/opt/gitlab/backups/`. Consider for example as a non-root user I run this command:

```
$ echo /var/*
/var/cache /var/db /var/empty /var/lib /var/lock /var/log /var/mail /var/run /var/spool /var/svc.d /var/tmp
```

Then the shell expands the `*` to the list of non-hidden files in that directory, then `echo` prints those values.

However, if I try to do the same thing with a directory that I don't have the ability to access:

```
$ echo /root/*
/root/*
```

The shell doesn't have permission to enumerate the content, and therefore cannot expand the `*`.

If you really must use the wildcard, then you can try:

```
$ sudo /bin/sh -c 'rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/backups/*'
```

With that, you run a new shell (`/bin/sh`) as root.  That shell will have permission to read the content of the directory and can expand `*` to the contents.